# Fit one model or several models to maximize power for significance testing of slopes in a factorial design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, statistical-power, categorical-encoding, lsmeans

## Problem

I need to perform a power analysis for a set of statistical tests. Each test is about a regression slope computed in a cell of a factorial experiment design. To minimize the required sample size, should I use (A) a different regression model for each test, each fitted to data-points from one cell, or (B) a single model fitted to all data-points, with factors and interactions encoded with dummy variables?

## Details

My experiment has a 3 $\times$ 3 $\times$ 2 within-subjects factorial design. In the experiment, $k$ participants each produce $p$ data-points in each cell of the design for a sample size of $n=3\times 3 \times 2 \times k \times p$. The data-point is $(X,Y)$, where $X$ is the continuous independent variable and $Y$ is the continuous dependent variable.

In each cell of the design, I am testing the following null hypothesis $H_0$ against the alternative hypothesis $H_1$:

- $H_0$: The slope for independent variable $X$ equals zero.
- $H_1$: The slope for independent variable $X$ is greater than zero.

Statistical power and significance threshold are the same in each cell. Effect size differs by cell.

Which of the following two approaches provides more statistical power?

### Approach A

Fit one model per cell. The model is a linear mixed effects model with a fixed slope and random intercepts and slopes by subject. Perform one statistical test per model.

### Approach B

Fit a single model. The model is a linear mixed effects model with a slope for the independent variable, dummy-coded categorical predictors for the factors, and all interaction terms. Estimate the slope in each cell as a linear combination of fixed effects coefficients (e.g., using R package `emmeans` or `lsmeans`). Perform all statistical tests on the single model.